# How can I prevent lint errors when checking if a class exists

Tags: php, phpstorm, lint

In my PHP project I have the following code:

```php
if (class_exists('\App\Subscription\Model\Instance')) {
    return new \App\Subscription\Model\Instance();
} else {
    return new \Framework\Subscription\Model\Instance();
}
```

Class `App\Subscription\Model\Instance` is not defined, so the block works as expected and falls into the `else`.

However PhpStorm is complaining about an undefined class `\App\Subscription\Model\Instance`, despite it being contained within the `class_exists` check.

I'm assuming it is doing this because it has no context as to what the string passed to `class_exists` is. On the off chance this function behaved as a language struct (similar to isset, etc) I tried using the `::class` suffix, whilst it compiled, the linter error remains.

Is there a way to suppress this error/warning?

Comment: From what I have found so far .. only this ticket (which was declined / workaround suggested) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16751. In general, if you have `new someClass` in your code, then such class must be resolved for IDE to be able to offer any completion later. If it does not (user will create own class outside of your library/framework) then either ignore it or use suppression for that line.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that one, but I agree it looks like this is a _won't fix_ situation (and I can understand why). If you want to ad your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised this doesn't work. There are other situations where its inspections are clever about things like this (wrapping some code in an `instanceof` check gives you completion of methods, for example), and this seems like quite a trivial case. Ah well.

Comment: @iainn I know, I thought exactly the same thing :(

Comment: @iainn *"There are other situations where its inspections are clever about things like this..."* But those are *different* situations. In such case more appropriate comparison would be with `method_exist()`...

Comment: @HelloPablo If you wish -- feel free to file a Feature Request ticket to [PhpStorm Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI). I just think that it will have the same fate as aforementioned ticket (but who knows ... + it does not cost anything)